# Graph API tokens and file_get_contents

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have problems with simple PHP function file_get_contents...
It shows NULL but it's enabled on the server so I don't know where is problem?

```
<?php
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=(ID)&
    client_secret=(PW)&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($url);
echo $app_token;
?>
```

(ID) and (PW) are appID and appSecret

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you type $url value directly in browser, then what you get ?

Comment: I get result with token...
In this format:
AppID|Token

Comment: what you get in var_dump($app_token) ?

Comment: I don't know what is var_dump... I use echo $app_token but please write me full syntax of var_dump

Comment: replace http with https in url and then try

Comment: see this to use cURL: https://illuminatikarate.com/blog/facebook-graph-api-requires-access-token-for-feed-access/

Comment: I already does this... It has no difference

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use php curl and https (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

HTTP instead of HTTPS would output:
    {
        "error": {
            "message": "client_secret must be passed over HTTPS",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 1
        }
    }

Please turn on error reporting during development. You may get:
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/xxxxx/test12345.php on line 3

Comment: Yea but I don't know how to use cURL :-P

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use HTTPS, and check what wrappers are enabled

On Windows you should see this in php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Check the wrappers

```
<?php
    var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());
?>
```

Which should give an output such as

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "https"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "ftps"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "compress.zlib"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "compress.bzip2"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "php"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "file"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "glob"
  [7]=>
  string(4) "data"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "http"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "ftp"
  [10]=>
  string(4) "phar"
  [11]=>
  string(3) "zip"
```

Notice HTTPS is in the array.

A full example of how to get the token

```
<?php 

    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    $app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
        . "&grant_type=client_credentials";

    $response = file_get_contents($app_token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    echo("This app's access token is: " . $params['access_token']);

 ?>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/